# How to make the GWT'S RichTextArea widget ReadOnly?

Tags: gwt

How to make the GWT'S RichTextArea widget ReadOnly?

Comment: Per @Mauricio : using setEnabled(false) doesn't work in GWT 2.7

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`isEnabled(false)`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FocusWidget.html#isEnabled%28%29) to make it read-only.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me - When I disable it before attaching the RichTextArea to the DOM for the first time it will work as expected, but when I disable it after it was already attach to the DOM and has been enabled, the method setEnabled(false) will make isEnabled() return false, but the text can still be modified.